# Setting a button background and color

Tags: java, android, button

I want to set a background and color to a same button.
Im using `setbackgroundResource` and `setBackgroundColor` to do so....however it only changes either the background or the color not both of them.

Is there any way to change button background and background color differently?

Comment: Can you post screenshot, what you want? I think background image and color both will be massed up and only one thing will display.

Comment: what do u want to set on the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the color of background image i.e. you set using `setBackgroundResource` then use

`setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black)));`

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you want to set a drawable as foreground and the color as background, you would need an ImageView. You can set it directly from the xml :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:src="@drawable/my_awesome_drawable" />
```

or programmatically like this :

```
imageView.background = resources.getDrawable(R.color.black)
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_awesome_drawable)
```